# Can't access URL link on Apache in CentOS7

Tags: php, apache, centos, httpd.conf, mod-security

I have a system using PHP, httpd (Apache 2) and mod_security on CentOS 7.0. This application is not programmed by me, I only operate and maintain.

I have a problem that some PC in my office cannot access the web application URL.

Here is URL:

[This is origin URL](http://wm.vnptdata.vn//?&mod=user), it has two character "//" in this link:

[image]

With two "//" character in url some PC can't access.

If I change from "//" to "/", it accesses successfully.

I want to change from "//" to "/" automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also Vietnamese.

```
<?php

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($uri, '//') !== false) {
    $uri = str_replace('//', '/', $uri);

    header("Location: $uri");
}
```

This is the change:

```
BEFORE: http://127.0.0.1/test.php//?&mod=server
AFTER: http://127.0.0.1/test.php/?&mod=server
```